# Loading rails console and defining a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and hit a snag on section 2.3.3

"We first invoke the console with rails console at the command line, and then retrieve the first user from the database using User.first (putting the results in the variable first_user):7"

Any help would be much apprecaited

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13)
1.9.3-p429 :001 > >> first_user = User.first
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tRSHFT
>> first_user = User.first
  ^
from /Users/MattPerloe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/MattPerloe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/MattPerloe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put `>>` before your code.

The `>>` in the tutorial is only to imply that the followed command is being entered in the rails console.

The following will be enough:

```
rails console
first_user = User.first
```

Comment: 1.9.3p429 :008 > first_user = user.first
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object

Derp. Thanks. Got it, I guess the U in Users is case sensitive?

Comment: Yea it is. you should just try